# When bind the real time data to listview from websocket app gets freeze in android

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

When i bind the data to listview from websocket in `onMessage()` and when   scroll app gets freeze . How can i make app fast like facebook.How do i bind the data to listview so that scrolling will not freeze the application.

```
mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketConnectionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onOpen() {

                    mConnection.sendTextMessage("{\"method\": \"data1\"}");
                    mConnection.sendTextMessage("{\"method\": \"data2\"}");


                    Log.d("Connected", "Connection Established");
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(final String payload) {
                    Log.d("data", payload);
                    try {


                        listview.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                try {

                                    JSONArray keyArray = new JSONArray(payload);
                                    JSONObject geyObj = keyArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(payload);

                                    switch (geyObj.keys().next()) {


                                        case "data1":


                                            orderList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
                                            JSONObject tenBidsTradeJobject = jarray.getJSONObject(0);
                                            JSONArray jArrayTenbidsTrade = tenBidsTradeJobject.getJSONArray("data1");
                                            JSONArray tenBidsJarray = (JSONArray) jArrayTenbidsTrade.get(0);
                                            orderList = filterOrderData(tenBidsJarray);
                                            orderAdapter = new OrderListArrayAdapter(getActivity(), orderList);
                                            listview.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
                                            listview.smoothScrollToPosition(10);

                                            break;
                                    }


                                    listview.smoothScrollToPosition(10);
                                }
                             catch (JSONException je) {
                                je.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                                }
                        });
```

Here is my adapter code .

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class OrderListArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<OrderBookBean> drawerList;


    public OrderListArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OrderBookBean> drawerList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.drawerList = drawerList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return drawerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return drawerList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView valueVolume, valueRate, valueTotal;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolderItem viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.listview_order_book, parent,
                    false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();


            viewHolder.valueVolume = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.order_book_listview_volume);
            viewHolder.mainLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_main_row_layout);


            viewHolder.valueRate = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.order_book_listview_rate);

            viewHolder.valueTotal = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.order_book_listview_total);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            convertView
                    .setTag(R.id.order_book_listview_volume,
                            viewHolder.valueVolume);
            convertView
                    .setTag(R.id.order_book_listview_rate,
                            viewHolder.valueRate);
            convertView
                    .setTag(R.id.order_book_listview_total,
                            viewHolder.valueTotal);

            convertView
                    .setTag(R.id.listview_main_row_layout,
                            viewHolder.mainLayout);


        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.
                valueVolume.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.
                valueRate.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.
                valueTotal.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.
                mainLayout.setTag(position);


        viewHolder.valueVolume.setText(drawerList.get(position)
                .getValueVolume());

        viewHolder.valueRate.setText(drawerList.get(position)
                .getValueRate());

        viewHolder.valueTotal.setText(drawerList.get(position)
                .getValueTotal());


        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            viewHolder.mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B1E0DA"));
            viewHolder.valueVolume.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#58595b"));
            viewHolder.valueRate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#58595b"));
            viewHolder.valueTotal.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#58595b"));

        } else {
            viewHolder.mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            viewHolder.valueVolume.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#58595b"));
            viewHolder.valueRate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#58595b"));
            viewHolder.valueTotal.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#58595b"));

        }
        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: please post relevant codes. It is unclear what you asking?

Comment: Dude. First need to check code and then we can suggest you !

Comment: @PiyushGupta can you please check my code now

Comment: Could please provide your adapter code?